# Access my ZF models (application/models) without a prefix/namespace?

Tags: php, zend-framework, model

My Zend Framework setup is like this:

```
/application
    /modules
    /models
    /configs
/library
/public
```

I want to access my models without needing prefixes or namespaces, like this:

```
new User() // Would refer to /application/models/User.php
```

I know this is a fairly simple problem, but I havn't been able to figure it out yet. I've also seen a lot of similar questions but none that I thing were this one exactly, but please forgive me if I am duplicating an existing question.

So far, I have tried changing appnamespace to "" in my config.ini with no success and adding
the following to my Bootstrap with no success:
    protected function _initAutoload()
    {

```
    $autoloader = new Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource(array(
        'namespace' => '',
        'basePath'  => APPLICATION_PATH . '/models',
    ));

}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the fallback autoloader..

In your Bootstrap file (or wherever you like), do this:

```
protected function _initAutoloader()
{
    Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance()->setFallbackAutoloader(true);
}
```

That will allow you to load any arbitrary class that is in your path, even if you've registered specific autoload prefixes in your application.ini

And to clarify, make sure you are pushing APPLICATION_PATH . "/models" into your include_path at some point..

Comment: Thanks! This solves my problem. I should note that Zend strongly recommends against using the Fallback Autoloader feature because it can potentially reduce performance and cause errors, but in my case, I see absolutely no performance decrease or errors with it enabled. I think as long as I stick strictly to the classname-to-filename pattern, I should be fine.

Comment: Yeah I've been using this approach in my applications in production for a long time with no issues.  I do this for my models and also for my forms.